# Create a list of files that can be downloaded from a list of links associated to the links

Tags: windows-8.1, download

I have a list of links (circa 1000) each of which allows me to download one file. I would like to create a table in which each row will contain the link and the name of the file that is downloaded through that link.

I am using a windows 8.1 computer in an intranet with no administrator rights (cannot install sowftware). Each link does not contain the name of the file (e.g.: http://example.com/download.php?id=1028312).

Comment: You may use `curl -I` or `wget -S` with for command to get the file link. Use cygwin or BusyBox or alternatives.

Comment: Cannot install it without administrator rights

Comment: @user3161330 Well then what you want isn't possible.  What you want requires either third-party software like curl or wget, or a PowerShell that uses the appropriate cmdlet but if your not an Administrator then stop doing something you don't have permission to do

Comment: Well, I could use a portable version. How would you use wget to write to a file (maybe a CSV) the link and the file name?

Comment: you didn't install BusyBox in Windows. Jut run it with normal CMD. Link:: https://frippery.org/busybox/index.html

Comment: Tell me the URL and I will give you the commands.